# Possible to handle parameters from POST and GET before rendering the GUI in ExtJS?

Tags: post, extjs, get

Is there any simple way to recieve POST and GET parameters from within an ExtJS application that are sent from outside the ExtJS application?

So, for example, when I press the link `www.go-to-my-extjs-homepage.com?parameter1=a&parameter2=b` my ExtJS application will recieve the params `parameter1=a&parameter2=b` before rendering the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to catch an incoming request, if it invokes some event:

```
Ext.Ajax.on(event_name, this.onBeforeRenderRequest, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to Application.js.

The init() method is run before the Viewport is created.

```
Ext.define(MyApp.Application', {
    name: 'MyApp',
    extend: Ext.app.Application',

    init: function(application){
        var params = Ext.Object.fromQueryString(window.location.search);
        console.log('parameter1: ' + params.parameter1);
        // process params
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```